# mandatory functions of ‘struct file_operations’

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to understand the concepts behind **character device driver** in **Linux kernel**. Basically I want to expose an IOCtl to user mode program. I implemented an '**struct file_operations->unlocked_ioctl**' and **dummy 'struct file_operations->open, ->close' callbacks**(**I mean these ->open, ->close callbacks always return true without any other logic**). So my doubt is do I really need to keep these API's? I tried removing these ->open->close callbacks in kernel mode driver and still I'm able to access IOCtl function from user mode. I'd like to know what are all the mandatory functions of ‘struct file_operations’ to be exposed in this scenario. Can someone please clarify me on this?

Answer (score 1):

In the `struct file_operations` object **none** of callback functions is **mandatory**.

When VFS (Virtual FileSystem) finds some function to be NULL, it may interpret it as **default implementation** (e.g. `.open()` and `.close()` simply returns 0 by default) or as "for given file, given functionality is **not supported**" (e.g., absence of `.write()` and some other fields means that given file doesn't support writing into it).

Fill only those function(s), which are needed to implement a functionality which you want.

---

The only field in `struct file_operations` which is *recommended* to fill, is the `owner` field. In most cases it should be set to `THIS_MODULE`:

```
.owner = THIS_MODULE
```

Such a way you will protect other callback functions from the module's *unloading*.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Regarding '.owner = THIS_MODULE' field in struct file_operations, what happens if we don't fill this field, can you please give some more details.

Comment: Without `.owner` field set, it is possible that some process will work with a file (e.g., executing `.unlocked_ioctl` function) but some other process will unloads the module at the same time. Unloading a module means unmapping the module's code and data, so execution of `.unlocked_ioctl` function will trigger page fault. With `.owner = THIS_MODULE` the module cannot be unloaded if any process works with the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understood that setting the struct file_operations .owner filed to THIS_MODULE prevents module to get unloaded when it is in operation. So I tried by removing this '.owner = THIS_MODULE' field from struct file_operations and triggered ‘rmmod’ while other process working with the file, but I’ve noticed failure in rmmod i.e. “rmmod: ERROR: Module test_module is in use”. But I’ve no idea why rmmod failed?

Comment: Probably, you use other mechanisms which prevent the module from being unloaded. Without viewing the code it is difficult to say more.